# Manipulate filters in arrayplot with graphical user interface

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, image-processing

I have a set of images which need to be filtered by different filters.
So I have made an interface in which the user can choose his or her filter.
However I now want to manipulate the degree of the filter. Meanfilter[imagedata, {1,2,3 etc.)]. I now have a working manipulate:

```
Manipulate[ArrayPlot[MedianFilter[imageDataOr, i]], {i, 0, 10, 1}]
```

but the image does not refresh when I use it in a graphical user interface. The code is:

```
outM = DialogInput[{
    TextCell["Adjust filter you want to use"],
    Row[{Manipulate[
       ArrayPlot[MedianFilter[imageDataOr, i]], {i, 0, 10, 1}]}],
    Button["Continue", DialogReturn[1]]}];

image=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekhbd.jpg"];
imageDataOr=ImageData[image]
```

[image: []]

EDIT: You have to grayscale the image.

To be specific. When I use the slider everything works fine, but when I click on a specific point it does not refresh

The solution is now:

```
butOut = DialogInput[{
   TextCell["Choose the filter you want to use"], 
   Button["Median Filter", DialogReturn[1]]}];
If[butOut == 1, outM = DialogInput[{
    TextCell["Adjust filter you want to use"],
    Row[{Manipulate[
       ArrayPlot[
        ImageData@MedianFilter[Image[imageDataOr], ManipulateI], 
        PreserveImageOptions -> False], {{ManipulateI, 1, "t1"}, 0, 
        10, 1}, SynchronousUpdating -> True, 
       LocalizeVariables -> False],
      Manipulate[
       ArrayPlot[
        ImageData@MedianFilter[Image[imageDataOr], ManipulateJ], 
        PreserveImageOptions -> False], {{ManipulateJ, 1, "t2"}, 0, 
        10, 1},
       SynchronousUpdating -> True, LocalizeVariables -> False]}],
    Button["Continue", DialogReturn[1]]}]; 
 originalCorrected = MedianFilter[imageDataOr, ManipulateI]; 
 movedCorrected = MedianFilter[imageDataMo, ManipulateJ];
 ];
```

Kind regards,

Glenn

Answer (score 2):

See [DialogInput > Possible Issues](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DialogInput.html)
as a possible explanation of the freeze issue.

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

It is also a good idea to be aware of [PreserveImageOptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PreserveImageOptions.html) which may also disconnect the control from the content.

So using the combination `PreserveImageOptions->False` for `ArrayPlot` and `SynchronousUpdating -> True` for `Manipulate` seems to fix the issue:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Tree"}];

outM = DialogInput[{TextCell["Adjust filter you want to use"], 
   Row[{Manipulate[ArrayPlot[ImageData@MedianFilter[img, i],
                   PreserveImageOptions->False], {i, 0, 10, 1},
       SynchronousUpdating -> True]}], 
   Button["Continue", DialogReturn[1]]}]
```

(* you could also use `ArrayPlot[MedianFilter[ImageData@img, i]]` but it is painfully slow. *)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have tested your program but this image is also not adjusting on the manipulated value. I don't know if this is due to the running time or something..

Comment: I see, and I have edited it now. But the problem I have now is when I don't use the slider. If I drag and drop everything works fine. But when I click on a specific point (without dragging) the image does not refresh. You know were this comes from? And when I start sliding again it does not work again and I have to restart the the evaluation

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now :)!! I have still a small question, how can I use the value of the manipulation in a new function?

Comment: @ kguler I have to add LocalizeVariables -> False in the manipulate and define the variables outside the Manipulate (make them global) I have updated the code

Comment: Glenn, we need to clean up the comments above (I will delete mine in a moment.) And please remember that if you find an answer useful, you can Upvote and/or Accept it.